# TabControl.Orientation?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol, orientation, tabitem

I wanna set a TabControl that its header are in the left side instead of on top, how do I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" >
</TabControl>
```